# Missing Json/Bootstrap files when creating a new project - Sencha Architect 3

Tags: json, file, extjs, directory, project

Most of the time I create a project I miss a lot of necessary files such as the bootstrap and Json files.

I have all the dependencies (Ruby, JDK, Apache Ant) and Sencha CMD 5.1 (6 gives me alot of problems), I have also set my custom Cmd Base Path to cmd/5.1.3.61

It's a lot like a hit in miss, i'll create and save a lot of projects in different places hoping that 1 will provide me with all the necessary files needed to code properly (had to create over 10 projects for me to get a project folder with all the files in, and save them all in different directories).

Anyone know the cause of this or how to fix it so that Sencha Architect will give me all the necessary files with each project I create?

I've tried Saving As the project folder to a different location, using sencha cmd web start, saving the entire project and (it's not letting me build the project as it is greyed out)

Also tried reinstalling sencha architect, cmd, and all its dependencies; problem still occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by turning on build tools (which should be enabled since I have all the dependencies) that then allowed me to build the project and get all the required files